# How to get generic class in java

Tags: java, oop, generics, superclass

For example, I have classes:

SuperClass.java:

```
public class SuperClass<A extends ClientsDTO> {

    ...
    private A getChildsGenericClass{
        //???
    }
}
```

User.java

```
class User extends SuperClass<UserDTO> {
    ...
}
```

So how can I access UserDTO's class in `SuperClass`'s in `getChildsGenericClass` method?

Comment: I know, it's possible to make getChildGenericClass abstract and override it in child class, returning new UserDTO, but it  is not the best solutions, i hope.

Comment: when you say to access UserDTO class, what is it that you are trying to access ?

Comment: @coder, for example, UserDTO.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public A example; //this is variable from you can get Class
private Class<Object> getChildsGenericClass() {
        return (Class)((ParameterizedType)
                 (this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()))
                                      .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

that actually works!

Answer (score 0):

you did not pass an **instance** of UserDTO to the superclass.
without instance, which objects fields do you want to access?

When you want to access UserDTO class, you can easily write:

```
Class c = UserDTO.class;
```

in other case, maybe you want something like this:

```
public class SuperClass<T extends ClientsDTO> {

    private Class<T> m_clz;
    public NewClass(Class<T> p_clz)
    {
       m_clz = p_clz;
    }

    private Class<T> getChildsGenericClass()
    {
       return m_clz;
    }
```

}

Comment: No, I wanted to access A class, that in THAT case is UserDTO.
Anyway, I did it via reflection.